# TKinter Button instantiation with list comprehension

Tags: python, tkinter, list-comprehension

I'm creating a GUI in tkinter, and am trying to use list comprehension for the creation of buttons.
However, I struggle getting the list comprehension to actually replace 'btn' with the names in 'btn_list'. I'd appreciate if anyone knew of a clever way of doing this.

```
start_btn, pause_btn, reset_btn, stat_btn = (Button(),) * 4
btn_list = [start_btn, pause_btn, reset_btn, stat_btn]

[btn.grid(row=2, column=col) for col, btn in enumerate(btn_list)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `(Button(),) * 4`, you get a tuple containing 4 times the same button. If you want 4 different buttons, you can do it with a list comprehension:

```
btn_list = [Button() for i in range(4)]
```

I do not see the point of using a list comprehension instead of a regular for loop to grid them though because it gives you a useless list of `None`.

Comment: I don't think using list comprehension like that is a problem, `None` is not assigned to anything and you get much more compact code, e.g. `[print(x) for x in xs if not x % 2]` instead of 3 lines when using regular `for`.

Comment: I want to avoid using 4 lines of code in order to create 4 `Button()` objects. As for the last part, I agree, but that doesn't work either, e.g., this: `for x in range(len(btn_list)):
    btn_list[x].grid(row=2, column=x)`

Comment: @matszwecja I am not saying it is a problem to use a list comprehension, maybe I should have formulated it differently. My point is that, in my opinion, writing compact code should not be the first priority, especially when learning, compared to writing clear and easy to understand code.

Comment: @j_4321 Agreed, but I don't think compact and easy to understand are mutually exclusive in that case.

Comment: @Aleins What do you mean precisely by does not work? If I run `btn_list[x].grid(row=2, column=x)` followed by either `[btn.grid(row=2, column=col) for col, btn in enumerate(btn_list)]` or the for loop version, I get 4 buttons in a row.

Comment: @j_4321 It didn't show any buttons because I hadn't implemented the `btn_list` as you did above. Changed it now and works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you create the button in a class instead, and add initiate the class for each item in the list comprehension, that should work.

```
import tkinter as tk


class CreateButton:
    """Create button class"""
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.button = tk.Button(**kwargs)


window = tk.Tk()
button_text = ["Test1", "Test2"]
buttons = [CreateButton(master=window, text=text, width=20) for text in button_text]
for button in buttons:
    button.button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It would be more useful to provide a code example, at the moment it is more a suggestion that should be posted as a comment than an answer (when you have more than 50 rep you will be able to comment on any post).